# How can I find for which values of $p$ this series converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The series is $\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k(\ln(k))^p}$. I know $\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k(\ln(k))}$ diverges but don't know how to go about finding where it's convergent.

Comment: You can use the Integral Test (set $u=\ln x$). If you want to be fancy, use Cauchy Condensation.

Comment: If you have proved that $\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{1}{k\log k}$ is divergent you have reasonably already used the integral test or the Cauchy condensation test. By applying one of them again, you will see that $\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{1}{k \log^p k}$ is convergent iff $p>1$.

Answer (score 1):

The integral test works well here:
$$\int_2^\infty\frac1{x(\ln x)^p}\,dx$$  Use the substitution $u=\log x$.

Comment: What do I do after taking the integral to find where it converges?

Comment: The integral test says that the series converges if and only if the improper integral converges.  So once you figure out which $p$ make the integral converge you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is cauchy condensation test.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k\ge 2}\frac 1{k^a}\ln^b k$$
is known as a Bertrand's series and is standard.

It is convergent if and only if $(a>1)$ or $(a=1\,$ and $\,b>1)$, in the first case by comparison with a Riemann series, and in the second case by the integral test.